# Wrong data type of kafka messages in landoop/fast-data-dev when sent via spring kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot app using Spring-Kafka and I am using [landoop's fast-data-dev](https://github.com/Landoop/fast-data-dev) in docker as my kafka cluster. 
I produce messages to some topic using kafka template, avro and confluent's schema registry. All seems to be working fine however when I enter fast-data-dev ui I can see my schema as registered and still my messages are visible as `Data type: binary` instead of 'avro' and therefore their values are not readable in ui. I tried sending some messages using kafka-avro-console-producer to a different topic and there is no such problem for those messages - they are visible as avro and readable in ui. However, when I send message using kafka-avro-console-producer to the same topic that my app was sending messages to, then it is visible in the same way as messages sent by my app (as binary).

Am I missing something on Spring-Kafka adding data type headers? Or maybe there is a completely different reason?

Here is a part of my application.yml:

```
spring.kafka:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  producer:
    key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    properties:
      schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
```

Also, when I use locally installed confluent platform messages are readable so maybe the problem is somewhere in fast-data-dev image?

Comment: Are you using kafka 2.0.1 with your spring boot app ? (landoop seems to use this version)

Comment: Check this issue : https://github.com/Landoop/kafka-topics-ui/issues/120
It looks like yours

Comment: @Gremi64 I looked up this issue and it seems that it is the key (which is not Avro) that causes the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

From the code of Landoop [Kafka-Topic-ui](https://github.com/Landoop/kafka-topics-ui/blob/master/src/factories/consumer.factory.js) line 21

There is a function taking the "format" in parameter. Assuming this `getDataFromBeginning` is the function retrieving all messages from a topic, if the "format" (binary, avro, ...) change... it won't works.

IMHO this is what cause your problem.